# React | Material-Ui | Swipeable Drawer not opening with swipe

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a new project and trying to create a "menu" or drawer. The idea is for it to open when the user swipes from the left side of the screen.
Here's a [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-dffoc?file=/demo.js) where it works.
Here is the [running example](https://dffoc.csb.app/) (you can run it on mobile)

It works for me, but when I try to run it locally it doesn't works as expected
It is the exact same code I have on both code-sandbox and locally.

I've noticed that my local: [image: My local]

Is different from the code-sandbox.
The code-sandbox has this extra `div`. But for some reason it is not working on my local [image: CodeSandBox]

Here is a list of my dependencies:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
"@material-ui/styles": "^4.10.0",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
"firebase": "^7.19.0",
"fontsource-roboto": "^3.0.3",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "3.4.3"
```

Am I missing something? I couldn't find it in the documentation, and because it works on the sandbox, I'm almost sure it is my fault somewhere, but I can't seem to get it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem wasn't actually with the code but more with the chrome "device emulator", it worked after reloading the browser and already having the "iOS device" pre-set.

I don't know if this is expected behavior.
Even with the specific lines on the documentation, it doesn't works.

```
const iOS = process.browser && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);

<SwipeableDrawer disableBackdropTransition={!iOS} disableDiscovery={iOS} />
```

Answer (score 2):

The `SwipableDrawer` doesn't work with the temporary or persistent variants of the Drawer. If you remove that prop it should work fine.

If you need to hide the backdrop you can do this:

```
            <SwipeableDrawer
                sx={{
                    '& .MuiBackdrop-root': {
                        display: 'none',
                    },
                }}
                anchor="left"
                open={ sidebarOpen }
                onClose={ () => dispatch( toggleSidebar() ) }
                onOpen={ () => dispatch( toggleSidebar() ) }
                BackdropProps={{ invisible: true }}
            >
                content
            </SwipeableDrawer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Swipe to open is disabled by default on IOS.
Set disableSwipeToOpen prop to false:

```
disableSwipeToOpen={false}
```